# Prove using a proof by contradiction: There is no smallest positive real number

Tags: real-numbers

Prove using a proof by contradiction: There is no smallest positive real number

Let us assume the contradiction: There is a smallest positive real number.

How do I continue?

Comment: You continue by constructing a smaller positive real number from it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to proofs and I've got a midterm tomorrow

Comment: Given $x > 0$, you probably can think of hundreds of ways to obtain an $y$ with $0 < y < x$ from $x$ within minutes, can't you?

Comment: So can I just say:
Assume there exists a smallest positive real number,x and x/2 is also real but its smaller. Therefore its a contradiction

Comment: Just here to point out that "contraction" isn't the word to use here. Should say "Let us assume the contradiction" although I recommend "we proceed toward contradiction" or "For the sake of contradiction, suppose..."

Comment: Almost. You also need to say that $x/2$ is positive too.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose there is a smallest positive number, say $s$. So what is $\frac{s}{2}?$

Comment: Short and sweet. Nice!