# Two example statements meant to demonstrate the importance of quantifier order don't appear to do so

Tags: proof-verification

In a book<sup>1</sup> I have encountered the following:

> To check your understanding of [the importance of quantifier order], consider the following two statements. One is true, and the other is false. Which is which?
>   $$ \exists y > 0\ \text{such that}\ \forall x > 0, y < x $$
>   $$ \forall x > 0\ \exists y > 0\ \text{such that}\ y < x $$

(The type of $x$ and $y$ aren't specified, but I've assumed they are real numbers)

I think I understand how the two statements are different. However, to me, both statements appear to be false:

Start by assuming either statement is true. Since $y < x$, we can state that $y = x - d$, where $d > 0$. Let us consider the case that $x = d$. Substituting $x$ for $d$ gives us: $y = d - d \implies y = 0$. This contradicts the requirement in both statements that $y > 0$. Both statements must be false.

Alternatively stated: Whatever the value of $y$, there is a value of $x$ where $x = y$, contradicting the requirement that $y < x$.

**Has the author made a mistake or am I making one? If so, please explain my mistake and help me understand which one is true, and why (with emphasis on the order of the quantifiers if possible).**

---

<sup>1</sup>*How to Study for a Mathematics Degree* by Lara Alcock, p73

Comment: You can say that there's _some_ $d$ such that $y=x-d$ - but you're 'assigning' $d$ (that is, effectively assigning a value to $y$) before assigning $x$.  In fact, for the truth of the second statement you (of necessity) have a _different_ $y$ (and a different $d$) for each $x$.

Comment: Statement 1 says you may fix $y$ first. It is easy to see that that does not work. Statement 2 says choose $x$ first and then search for $y$ (which may depend on $x$). You can take $y=x/2$.

Comment: The second can be read as follows: If you give be an $x\gt 0$, I can produce a $y\gt 0$ such that $y\lt x$. Sure can.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand how my disproof can't work for statement 2 now. I now realise what was confusing me: I was mistakenly thinking that there'd be a smallest possible value of $x$ (i.e. if you can set $y$ to $x/2$ then you can set $x$ to the same value and eventually there won't be some $y < x$). I didn't think about the fact that you can keep halving reals indefinitely. What should I do with this question? Write an answer? Delete?

Comment: @curiousinternals It would be good if you wrote an answer, no need to delete - other people may have the same question later

Comment: Given that it appears to me to already be a duplicate (see my note above), deleting it might be in order if you're amenable to doing such; it's certainly your choice.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The linked post doesn't address my second misunderstanding about there being a smallest possible $x$ where $x > 0$, so I'm going to go ahead and write an answer (might take a while). I'll probably reference that post in my answer though.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki After further thought, I don't think the question is a duplicate at all. In the end I realised I wasn't confused about the quantifiers (Thank goodness! I'd already used those two years ago): See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement is false, but the second is true.

## Proofs

### First Statement

The first statement is false if for every value of $y$, there is at least one value of $x$ that is not greater than $y$. A couple of examples are $y/2$ and $y$. Neither of these will ever be less than or equal to zero, so are valid values for $x$.

### Second Statement

$x/2$ is always less than $x$ but greater than zero, thus there is always a suitable value for $y$ to take.<sup>1</sup>

## Why I Was Incorrect

### Self Contradiction

Assuming the first or second statement to be true, for $y = x - d$ to be true, $d > 0$ and $d < x$ must also be true. Under these conditions $x \ne d$. In other words, **my** statement contradicted the other two statements; The other statements did not contradict **themselves**. A proper proof by contradiction needs to show how the assumption leads to a contradiction, not how arbitrary statements can contradict the assumption. I could have stated $y = 0$ straight away and it would have been just as invalid.

### Finding the Smallest Positive Real

Another mistake I made was thinking that there can be some smallest value of $x$ that is still greater than zero. This is why I was confused in the first place. Since $x > 0$, [there is no smallest possible value](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/959865/211145):

> Let's suppose there is a smallest positive number, say $s$. So what is ${s \over 2}$?

---

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to [Thomas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/128832/thomas) and [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%c3%a9-nicolas) for pointing this out in the comments.